# Multidimensional array for a text based game

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I'm trying to create a text based game, and someone suggested I store map data as a multi-dimensional array I have been trying to figure out how I'd do this or how I'd even navigate through a multi dimensional array. It seems to me this would be incredibly difficult but I have to ask because I won't be able to figure it out on my own. If this question is too vague let me know what should be more specific.

Comment: What kind of game is it, what's the main idea?

Comment: @Markus Meskanen It's kind of like Zork, in terms of the way navigation is set up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manually create a multi-dimensional *list*:

```
world_map = [['*', '*', '*', '*'],
             ['*', ' ', 'i', '*'],
             ['*', ' ', ' ', '*'],
             ['*', '*', '*', '*']]
```

Where `*` is a wall and `i` could be the player.
To loop through this world map, use two for loops:

```
for row in world_map:
    for column in row:
        print(column, end="")
    print()
```

This would print the world map.

If you need to move player left, you can do something like:

```
for row in world_map:
    for i, column in enumerate(row):
        if column == "i":
            if i > 0 and row[i - 1] == ' ':
                row[i - 1] = 'i'
                row[i] = ' '
```

You can also access elements directly with `world_map[row][column]` if you know the position of your element.

You're gonna have to do the rest by yourself.
Also, this might not be the best approach, you should use class for player, etc. but this works fine for beginners :)

Comment: Thanks a lot this information really helps with how I should move around the map and the clear explanation is great too.

Answer (score 2):

A multi-dimensional array is nothing more than an array whose elements map to another array, typically where each of these "sub-arrays" are equal in size (but not strictly).

```
inner = [ "" ] * 10
outer = [ [].extend(inner) for x in inner ]
```

This will create you a square multidimensional array 10 x 10 elements.

You can access those elements as:

```
outer[outer_index][inner_index]
```

Just visualize outer and inner and indices on a grid, with outer traversing the x-axis and inner traversing the y-axis.  The above array would look somewhat like this:

```
"" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" 0
"" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" 1
"" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" 2
"" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" 3
"" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" 4  (inner)
"" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" 5
"" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" 6
"" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" 7
"" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" 8
"" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" 9
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9

         (outer)
```

If I update the value of outer at elements 6 and 8, the grid would be changed:

```
outer[6][8] = "X" # marks the spot

"" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""  0
"" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""  1
"" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""  2
"" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""  3
"" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""  4  (inner)
"" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""  5
"" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""  6
"" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""  7
"" "" "" "" "" "" "X" "" "" "" 8
"" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""  9
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9

         (outer)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This does help I was overlooking the need to assign inner and outer coordinates.